# Choosing the right DPI-Setting

Tags: screen, user-interface

My Nexus 5x has a setting for the DPI (using cyanogenmod).

When is use the default 420, twitter doesn't display the cog-icon on profile pages (block, list, mute, ...). Using 400 i get the icon again, but the pebble app doesn't show the install button for apps. Choosing 380, the pebble app works again, but twitter is broken again.

Is there some "safe" DPI setting? Seems like apps assume some dpi and have parts of their interface hidden at "wrong" DPI settings. But when the optimal DPI differs between apps it's really annoying. Despite that i would prefer to choose DPI by my preferences instead of being forced to use a certain setting to avoid misbehaviour of apps.

Answer (score 1):

Xposed + App Settings is what you're looking for. You can modify DPI on a per-app basis and keep system DPI intact. Since the Marshmallow compatible version is not in the official Xposed repo, I reuploaded a copy to my own [AndroidFileHost](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=24686681827313216). You're already on CM so Xposed installation shouldn't be a problem for you either.

Comment: I already have Xposed, so this sounds like a good solution. Why isn't it in the official repository anymore? And i wonder if there is some more standard solution. I cannot believe, that apps really won't work at some dpi settings.

Comment: @allo Official version stops at 1.10 (for KitKat), and the newer ones are stated by the dev to be alpha, so they never made it inside. There are much more apps that hate DPI change than you think - for example Samsung's TouchWiz launcher will show a mess when not on a standard DPI. It all comes down to whether the app dev has compatibility in mind, I guess.